# Advice on web api unity and lifetime of repositories

Tags: unity-container, asp.net-web-api

I'm just running some tests with `web api and unity`, I have created a simple product repository and registered it with unity

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    private int _nextId = 1;

    public ProductRepository()
    {
        Add(new Product { Name = "Tomato soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1.39M });
        Add(new Product { Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M });
        Add(new Product { Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M });
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return products;
    }
    ... etc

 container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>((new HierarchicalLifetimeManager()));
```

when instantiated the product repository populates itself with 3 products so calls to products
api/Products returns all products.

The controller is initialised

```
 private IProductRepository _repository;

    public ProductsController(IProductRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
```

by using the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` I was expecting that if I put to the controller and then subsequently get that the previously put item would exist, this is not the case and the repository is initialized with every call, I'm only prototyping at the moment so don't want a `dbcontext` but want the repositories state to persist with multiple calls sort of singleton I suppose. any pointers on how this works or what I should do?

Comment: Where are you performing your registration, In Global.asax?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager instead. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec34.

> The default lifetime manager for the RegisterType method is the TransientLifetimeManager and the default lifetime manager for the RegisterInstance method is the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager. If you want the container to create or return a singleton instance of a type when you call the Resolve method, you can use the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager type when you register your type or instance.